# Pass Query into Function using AJAX (Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function, parameters

I'm trying to pass PHP Function parameters using Javascript (not JQuery) AJAX. Do I somehow add it to the javascript AJAX function send() ? Also i'm POSTing it to my PHP file.

The main thing is how do I use the XMLhttp.send() function to asynchronously call a PHP function while add parameters to the function.

Comment: http://whacked.net/2007/11/27/passing-parameters-to-xmlhttprequests-onreadystatechange-function/

Comment: I'm using POST - I've edited it to reflect that note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call a specific PHP function from Javascript.  The client doesn't know anything about the server side functions, and and the server side doesn't know anything about the client.  `jimbojw`'s answer explains how to pass parameters into PHP and handle them in PHP.  If you want to call a specific PHP function and return the results to the client, then you're going to have to have code to figure out *which* function to call on the server, or make a separate php file for each function you want to call.

If you want to go the first route, then you'd pass in something like an 'action' parameter, and then do this in your PHP file that contains the functions you want to call:

```
switch($_POST['action']) {
   case 'foo':
       foo($_POST['bar']);
       break;
   case 'foo2':
       foo2($_POST['bar']);
       break;
}
```

Comment: So how do people make multiple AJAX calls in one page that do completely different things? Do they make separate PHP files to deal with it or is it better to do what your saying and make one big PHP file that handles all of your AJAX/PHP needs?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the code.  For quick, simple, small functions, I'd probably have one file that contains everything.  For a larger, more complex function, you'd probably want a single file (and likely, break up the single function into multiple functions that get called in sequence).  It's hard to say what the best route is without seeing the code and the entire system.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will receive the request from JavaScript in the form of a POST or GET.  Use the standard `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals to access the values.

#### edit - sorry, misunderstood the question

Yes, use XMLHttpRequest's [`send()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) method.  Ex:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ...
xhr.send("x=y&foo=bar");
```

Then, in PHP:

```
echo( $_POST['foo'] ); // echos "bar"
```

Comment: Still though, how would I use the XMLHttpRequest method to call the function and add the parameters?

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking a number of separate questions: 1) How do I call a function in PHP? 2) How do I access incoming request variables in PHP? 3) How do I send data to a webserver asynchronously from the client? etc ... So, it's hard to tell exactly what you need help with.

Comment: I know how to call a function in PHP, I know how to send data asynchronously from the client, what I don't know is how to combine the two. I don't know how to asynchronously call a PHP function with added parameters. Sorry for the confusion I've edited my post. Hopefully this clears it up.

Comment: My (updated) answer demonstrates how to call the echo function, passing in a parameter received from AJAX.  So, as far as I can tell, your requirements have been met.

Comment: See with your explanation I would have to call every function. If I have multiple functions in my PHP file that deal with AJAX it could become troublesome.

Comment: Without knowing what your code does and how it's laid out, it's hard to provide more guidance.  It sounds like your code may need a refactor.  The real question is what do you want the code to actually do - then create functions as appropriate to achieve this.